# How to disconnect Google Colab after finishing script

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab Pro+ to train a computer vision model. Sometimes execution takes up to 8 hours so after completion I'm still allocating memory and a GPU. I wish I had a line of code to execute after the training finishes. Is there any way to terminate the environment using code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to disconnect your runtime by running the following command,

```
!kill $(ps aux | awk '{print $2}')
```

This command will extract the PID of each running process and then kill (or stop) them.

Comment: Works well, thank you!